# How to mutate a mobile phone number in django-graphene?

Tags: graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a customer model in django.

```
#models.py    
class Customer(models.Model):
        name =  models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
        mobile = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
        recent_visit_time = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

#forms.py
class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name','mobile']

#mutations.py
class CustomerMutation(DjangoModelFormMutation):
    class Meta:
        form_class = CustomerForm
```

I am using `ModelForm` to create a graphene-django mutation. I am able to add a mobile number from the admin panel, but unable to do so via a mutation. I want to add a 10 digit number but GraphQL only allows me to add 9 digit numbers.

I am getting following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Int cannot represent non 32-bit signed integer value: 88776655433"
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "customer": [
      {
        "id": "2",
        "mobile": null,
        "name": "Harsh Behl"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you receive an error message? You mention that "GraphQL only allows you to add 9 digits numbers", which needs more elaboration. What exactly do you mean?